# How to use both recusion and inheritance in XML Schema?

Tags: xsd

I have a use case to define XSD schema to describe a structure that is similar to Files and Directories.

1. `File` is a complex type with multiple attributes.
2. `Directory` is a `File`, so it should be an extension of a `File` or in other words, inherited from a `File`.
3. `Directory` can contain more `Files` and sub `Directories`, so it should be defined recursively.
4. `File` could be an element.
5. `Directory` could be an root element.

Can anyone provide an example schema file?

For example, the following C++ code compiles/runs fine:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    class FileClass {
    public:
       string name;
       int   type;
       string path;
       long long size;
       virtual int open(){
       };
       virtual int close (){
       };
       virtual ~FileClass(){
       };
    };

    class DirectoryClass: public FileClass {
    public:
       vector<FileClass*> dir_contents;
    };

    int main() {
    cout<<"started"<<endl;
    DirectoryClass root;
    root.open();
    FileClass* newFile = new FileClass();
    root.dir_contents.push_back(newFile);
    DirectoryClass* subDir = new DirectoryClass();
    root.dir_contents.push_back(subDir);
    root.close();
    cout<<"finished"<<endl;
    }
```

As you can see, the DirectoryClass contains only one vector of FileClass, and it's capable of storing sub dirs since DirectoryClass is derived from FileClass.

Comment: Why is directory a file? Besides the idea is you provide your current effort, we help. It's not we do your job for you in the vain hope of 15 rep points.

Comment: From file system point of view, a directory is just another file whose content is the mapping of filenames to inodes, thus they both have similar attributes such as name,size,permission,change-time,etc. I'm thinking that in the real C++/Java/C# code, such concept should be modeled easily with inheritance/recursion structure. Actually, my intention was to translate back/forth between XML and such data structures in C#/C++/Java.

Comment: The map is not the territory. As far as a physical storage system goes a directory is a file, you indicated no reason for your model to include that feature though. If I chose the inheritance route for this (unlikely to be honest) I'd have them both inherite from say a PhysicalFile Class. Far more likely I'd use aggregation in this scenario than inheritance though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Tony, why derive Directory from File? 
But if thats what your trying to model...

[image: Graphical Representation of XSD]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="FileType">
        <xs:attribute name="name"
                      type="xs:string"
                      use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="creationDate"
                      type="xs:dateTime"
                      use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="File"
                type="FileType" />
    <xs:element name="Directory">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="FileType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="File"
                                    minOccurs="0"
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        <xs:element ref="Directory"
                                    minOccurs="0"
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then if you are then trying to read/write the structured XML data from C#, C++, Java etc you could look at [XML Data Binding](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-data-binding.aspx). This generates a set of strongly typed objects from your XSD.

Comment: Thanks to all. Really appreciate your opinions. However, I'm thinking

Comment: Let's put aside whether using inheritance is correct logically. Just from the grammar point of view, the above C++ works fine, as you can see, the DirectoryClass contains one vector to store both Files and Directories under it. While in Sprotty's XSD file, the Directory has to contain both File and Directory.

Comment: I just added an example C++ code in my original question. Please refer to that code (somehow I cannot post here in correct format).

Comment: So there is no way to make Directory to contain only File?

Comment: Use <xs:element name="Directory" substitutionGroup="File"> and then you can get rid of <xs:element ref="Directory"...> within.

Answer (score 0):

That changes things a bit and compilcates the XML. There are 2 approaches ComplexType Inheritance or Substitution Groups. Complex Types are a better fit to the breif.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="FileType">
        <xs:attribute name="name"
                      type="xs:string"
                      use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="creationDate"
                      type="xs:dateTime"
                      use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="type"
                      type="xs:int" />
        <xs:attribute name="size"
                      type="xs:long" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DirectoryType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="FileType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Content"
                                type="FileType"
                                minOccurs="0"
                                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Directory"
                type="DirectoryType" />
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Directory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FoldersCT.xsd"
           name="string"
           creationDate="1975-12-12T08:25:00.94"
           type="393"
           size="-5191">
    <Content name="FileA1"
             creationDate="1993-02-23T21:13:52.11"
             type="4931"
             size="-1984" />
    <Content name="FileA2"
             creationDate="1991-12-26T15:57:44.30"
             type="-6155"
             size="18" />
    <Content name="FileA3"
             creationDate="1979-01-05T21:36:13.80"
             type="8362"
             size="5579" />
    <Content xsi:type="DirectoryType"
             name="DirA4"
             creationDate="1979-01-05T21:36:13.80"
             type="8362"
             size="5579">
        <Content name="FileB1"
                 creationDate="1979-01-05T21:36:13.80"
                 type="8362"
                 size="5579" />
        <Content name="FileB2"
                 creationDate="1979-01-05T21:36:13.80"
                 type="8362"
                 size="5579" />
    </Content>
</Directory>
```

Note the use of the xsi:type="DirectoryType" attribute in the directories. This tells the XML Parser that the content is defined by DirectoryType. Without this its a file. This is what your spec says, but its pretty messy I would say.

Another solution is to use substitution groups, which personally I don't like as they are difficult to read in a schema. This effectivley this is the same as the orginal solution.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="FileType">
        <xs:attribute name="name"
                      type="xs:string"
                      use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="creationDate"
                      type="xs:dateTime"
                      use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="type"
                      type="xs:int" />
        <xs:attribute name="size"
                      type="xs:long" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="File"
                type="FileType"
                substitutionGroup="File" />
    <xs:element name="Directory"
                substitutionGroup="File">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="FileType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="File"
                                    minOccurs="0"
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Directory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FoldersSG.xsd"
           name="string"
           creationDate="1992-01-13T17:58:08.38"
           type="-2296"
           size="-8752">
    <File name="string"
          creationDate="1982-11-03T17:57:40.96"
          type="6813"
          size="5278" />
    <File name="string"
          creationDate="1986-12-08T12:38:03.46"
          type="4479"
          size="8453" />
    <Directory name="string"
               creationDate="1992-01-13T17:58:08.38"
               type="-2296"
               size="8752">
        <File name="string"
              creationDate="1982-11-03T17:57:40.96"
              type="6813"
              size="5278" />
        <File name="string"
              creationDate="1986-12-08T12:38:03.46"
              type="4479"
              size="8453" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```